# Precision in numerical methods using Octave

Tags: numerical-methods, roots, bisection, octave

I have created an algorithm for the bisection method using Octave and tested it on two different functions.
The fist one worked flawlessly within the required tolerance. The second, however, won't give me a more precise result even when I increase the tolerance, despite it never coming close to the maximum number of iterations. I have included the code below without its commentary since it's not in english. That being said, in order to be clear:

$f$ is a continuous real function defined in $[a,b]$

$a$ is the lower bound

$b$ is the upper bound

$tol$ is the minimum error tolerance for the solution

$max\_iteracoes$ is the maximum number of iterations the program is allowed to run.

```
function [valor_approx,total_de_iteracoes] = metodo_da_bissecao(f,a,b,tol,max_iteracoes)

  if sign(f(a))*sign(f(b))>0
    printf('Error')
    return
  endif

  iteracoes = 1;

  while iteracoes <= max_iteracoes 
    p_i=a+(b-a)/2; 
    f_p_i=f(p_i); 
    valor_approx = p_i; 
    total_de_iteracoes = iteracoes; 

    if f_p_i==0 || abs((b-a))/2<tol 
      printf('The root of the function is : %d \n',valor_approx);
      printf('The number of iterations was: %d \n',total_de_iteracoes);
      return
    endif

    iteracoes = iteracoes+1; 

    if sign(f(a))*sign(f(p_i))>=0 
      a = p_i;
    else
      b = p_i;
    endif
  endwhile

  if iteracoes > max_iteracoes 
    printf('Fail! \n')
    return
  endif

 endfunction
```

Here are the functions I used to test it out:

```
f = @(x) exp(x) - x - 1

g = @(x) 3*x^3 + sqrt(2)*x^2 - pi*x + 0.4

format long

metodo_da_bissecao(f,-1,0,1.e-09,100);

metodo_da_bissecao(g,-2,-1,1.e-09,100);
```

function $f$ returns the following solution: $-1.49012e-08$ within $26$ iterations.

which I double-check, $f(-1.49012e-08) = 0$

function $g$ returns: $-1.33243$ within $24$ iterations.

which I double-check, $g(-1.33243) = 3.664661882629705e-05$

I've tried increasing the tolerance all the way to $1.e-15$, but the solution never changes nor does it reach the maximum number of iterations.

I'm puzzled as to what might be the problem with function $g$'s root.

Comment: Do you just copy the results? Then of course the output is no more accurate than the input. `%d` in the print format is usually for integers, use `%20.15g` for the root position.

Comment: The answers you provided for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ both have exactly six digits in the mantissa, suggesting that the language might print six digits either by default or as instructed by the program.  I would try a print statement with exp(1) (or similar) and see if it gives you six digits like both of your answers.  If it does, then this is more likely a print format issue rather than a precision issue.  The number  −1.33243 implies something like −1.332430000, whereas when I try a bisection algorithm on $g(x)$ in R I get  -1.33243404 for a tolerance of 1e-09 and -1.33243404126926 for 1e-15.

Comment: Thanks for both of your comments. The issue, as pointed out, was simply Octave's printing format. 
The problem was solved by calling the variable instead of having it printed.